# c# webbrowser: turn off all error messages

Tags: c#, .net, browser

is it possible to turn off any error messages that will be displayed because of script errors on the webpage?

Comment: Um, yes?  What web browser?  Is this Asp.Net?  Is this a control in a WinForms project?  You need to provide information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're speaking of the WebBrowser control, this should do the trick:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed.aspx

Answer (score 1):

set the property ScriptErrorsSuppressed to true in the web browser control properties. This suppose to solve this problem

//
When ScriptErrorsSuppressed is set to true, the WebBrowser control hides all its dialog boxes that originate from the underlying ActiveX control, not just script errors. Occasionally you might need to suppress script errors while displaying dialog boxes such as those used for browser security settings and user login. In this case, set ScriptErrorsSuppressed to false and suppress script errors in a handler for the HtmlWindow.Error event. For more information, see the code example in this topic.

//
reference MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed.aspx